# entities relations with doctrine (symfony 2)

Tags: symfony

I  start a project with symfony. I debute with the design of the data base.

My project consist to manage the treatment cycle of the an patient with several entites.

concretely: An entity patient should have a relation with social security entity, hospital, pharmacy, doctor , nurse, Personne to contact, and other.

The question is, what is the best data base schema the organize relations between entites using doctrine with symfony.

Should i use one to one and one to many , many to many directly between patient entity and the other entites or using and intermediate table.

Thank you in advance for your answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't do it with intermediate tables, just in the case that I explain below, so...

Patient could be in different hospitals databases - ManyToMany

Patient must be in just one social security (In the same country) - ManyToOne

Patient could be in different pharmacies databases - ManyToMany

Patient just has one General Doctor - ManyToOne

Patient could has more than one Person to contact - ManyToMany

Patient could has more than one nurse taking care of him - ManyToMany

---

Maybe I'm wrong in some of them, if it's like this correct me

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html

Check how to connect them through Doctrine, you should create a intermediate 
table when you're going to use this connection quite a lot